# Android, launch media file in player without starting playback

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm writing an app where I'm trying to select a file from storage and launch it with the default player for its type, or show a chooser. Right now, when the media player launches, playback starts immediately. I'd like it to load the file and wait for user input. Is there an extra I can add to my intent to tell the media player not to start playback?

```
// I have directory, filename, and mimeType defined in earlier code
File file = new File(directory, filename);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager() != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: some code would really help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

---

There are no documented extras for [the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW). With thousands of device models, and thousands more media players available for download, even if you found some undocumented, unsupported extra for one of those players, none of the others will necessarily support it.

I am not aware of any standard `Intent` action for "here's a media file, set it up but do not start playback".

Invoking third-party apps with an `Intent` is a bit like linking to a Web site from your site: what that site does in response to a user clicking that link is up to that site, not you. The `Intent` approach is worse in many ways, in that with a link to a site, you are linking to a specific site and you know the site should be available. With Android, the `Intent` might bring up any number of possible apps.

Comment: Thank you, both for your answer and the useful analogy!

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if i am wrong but from what i know there is no way to do that with the native player because its like launching a new app on which you do not have much of control.

I would suggest the use of [VideoView](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-videoview-example/) for such functionality that you are looking for. With this way you can handle when video will start, this is a really basic code example:

```
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
```

And in your play button click event: `myVideoView.start()`;

Comment: I apologize, I will edit my question to include the code. I'm not using a VideoView, but am launching the default video player on the device.

Comment: @Rae thanks for adding the code mate i have edited my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm working with someone else on this, and wanted to be sure before saying it's impossible to tell an external app not to begin playback right away.